# how to create a row that stores data in Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm a newbie, and I am trying to create a GPA calculator for my first app, so pardon me if I'm not clear. I am basically trying to create a GPA app which behaves similarly to this website http://registrar.uiowa.edu/gpa-calculator

And this is my app:

[image: my app]

As you see I have added text fields to collect the input, but the main problem occurs when the user tries to add more number of courses. Is there a certain method to do this? Because as of now I'm using code like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mycourse: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var mygrade: UITextField!
```

and so on.

Comment: You should look into UITableView/UITableViewController.

Answer (score 2):

This method is not really going to achieve what you're after. What you need is some sort of structure to present your text fields. I would suggest either UITableView or UICollectionView. Trying to implement these is not always the simplest when first starting out, so I would suggest reading up on it a little more before you begin. UITableView will be the most friendly to start with.

Here is a link to get you started with a UITableView:
https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/